# Symfony 2 - the entity class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, entity

I am trying to implement an internet application using Symfony 2 Framework. I created the entity class, which class I instantiated in the controller and I fullfilled the variables of that class with the data - it worked, but when I tried to send that data to the database - it failed (for some reasons, the persist method failed - of which I got to know because I placed the persist method in the try-catch() block of code).

In the Web browser I received the informaction as below:

```
string 'The class 'AppBundle\Entity\Practice_Words' was not found in the 
chain configured namespaces ' (length=93)
```

Code of the Controller:

```
<?php

  namespace AppBundle\Controller;

  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use AppBundle\Entity\Practice_Words;

  class DefaultController extends Controller
  {
  /**
   * @Route("/", name="homepage")
   */


   public function indexAction()
   {

    $practiceWords = new Practice_Words();
    $practiceWords->setEnglishWord("kind");
    $practiceWords->setPolishWord("rodzaj");

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    try{
    $em->persist($practiceWords);
    $em->flush();
    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
   }
 }
```

Entity - Practice_Words:

```
<?php

  namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 /**
  * Practice_Words
  */
 class Practice_Words
 {
 /**
  * @var int
  */
     private $id;

 /**
  * @var string
  */
     private $englishWord;

/**
 * @var string
 */
    private $polishWord;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set englishWord
 *
 * @param string $englishWord
 *
 * @return Practice_Words
 */

public function setEnglishWord($englishWord)
{
    $this->englishWord = $englishWord;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get englishWord
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEnglishWord()
{
    return $this->englishWord;
}

/**
 * Set polishWord
 *
 * @param string $polishWord
 *
 * @return Practice_Words
 */
public function setPolishWord($polishWord)
{
    $this->polishWord = $polishWord;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get polishWord
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPolishWord()
{
    return $this->polishWord;
}
```

Code of config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where     
  the  app is deployed

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices  
  /configuration.html#application-related-configuration
 parameters:
 locale: en

 framework:
 #esi:             ~
 #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
 secret:          "%secret%"
 router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"



 # Doctrine Configuration
 doctrine:
    dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true

    # Swiftmailer Configuration
    swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Could you please point me out what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the doctrine mapping of the entity? Maybe you forgot that?

Comment: gvf did you mean the yml headers of getters and setters which are in the entity class?

Comment: No, I mean this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Comment: I remowed all the entity, removed the table from the database, generated one more time the entity, but this time instead of yml I chose the annotation and it looks the same as under the link you sent to me but still there is the same error. I checked the names of the columns in the database with these in the enitty class and these are ok. Only the name of the database table has got the underscore added (so there are two as in my class name there is one 'Practice_Words') and in the database there are also in the table name two underscores.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be in your class naming.
According to PSR-4 Class names must be wrote down in CamelCase. And for doctrine your class
'AppBundle\Entity\Practice_Words' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Practice\Words.php'
Try renaming your class and check your database table names.

Comment: Ozz Mium as yuu suggested I renamed the class first to PracticeWords - it didn't work, and afterwards I renamed the class again to practiceWords - which didn't work either. I have even tried to put the back slash in the 'use' - use \AppBundle\Entity\..\ and when in the class name the was an underscore I placed the backslash in the place of the underscore instead of the underscore which also didn't work. I have tried while creating the object in the indexMain, to do sth like practiceWords = new \practiceWords(); - all the time I have got the same error.

Comment: When you changed to `PraticeWords` did you remember to modify your `config.yml` to remove the line `naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore` ?

Comment: Jason Roman yes, I removed this line: naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore from config.yml, cleared the cash, and there is still the same error.